# After creating .bash_profile...Terminal not working

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osx-yosemite

I created a new `.bash_profile` file and entered the following:

```
export PATH="usr/local/bin:usr/local/sbin:usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

I then deleted `.profile`. Because from what I learn't it causes conflicts having two profiles. But now none of the commands are working in the terminal! I'm using OS X Yosemite.

Comment: I've deleted PATH="usr/local/bin:usr/local/sbin:usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

Comment: and the commands are working again...but all I have is an empty .bash_profile file

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/guides.html -> Two guides on using bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start each path with `/`, otherwise that path will be relative to the current working directory, instead of an absolute path from the root of the filesystem. I wouldn't have expected that to cause a problem, but maybe `bash`'s parser for the PATH variable choked on the relative paths.

So you need:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Actually the PATH contains just some components when searching for an executable, starting with a `/` or not. Could that be a new Bash bug?

Comment: @ott-- I'm thinking maybe all the commands he cared about were in `/usr/local/*`

Comment: Ok, I misread that topic "Terminal not working". :-)